# Reach URL that has been dynamically set in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, url

I have a very simple one-page website with four tabs. Clicking on a tab will show one div with content and hide all three other divs and their respective content. I also change the URL with javascript `window.history.pushState`, so that I go from `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/Tab2Title`.

Obviously the page `http://www.example.com/Tab2Title` does not exist, so I get a 404 error when I refresh the page after having changed the URL. I then realized that people might want to copy the URL to send it, save it or whatever. Is there a way to load the page with the content of tab2 based on the URL? So that when people load the URL I can display the right content and not a 404 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can configure your web server to redirect all of the tab URLs to the same page. For example, make it so visiting `http://www.example.com/Tab2Title` keeps the URL as it is, but shows the same content that would be shown at `http://www.example.com/`.

The exact code to do this redirecting depends on what web server you are using. For example, it’s different if you have a static website with Apache, or a PHP site, or a Ruby on Rails site.

On the JavaScript side, you should add a “DOM ready” event handler to that single page. The code in that handler should look at the value of `window.location`, extract the part of the URL that changes for each tab, and show the tab that corresponds to it.

---

If you are willing to change your existing URLs, there is an easier-to-implement solution. Instead of linking to `http://www.example.com/Tab2Title`, link to `http://www.example.com/#Tab2Title`. In a URL, a part like `#Tab2Title` is called a fragment identifier, and means a link to one section of the page before the `#`, which is loaded all at once. All web servers should by default treat visiting `http://www.example.com/#Tab2Title` the same as visiting `http://www.example.com/`, except when the page loads, the browser will look for an element with `id="Tab2Title"` and scroll  to it if it exists. You can still use `window.location` in JavaScript to change the page contents as I mentioned above, even if there is no element with that ID on the page.

Comment: You're right, it's way better using the fragment identifier. It works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use # tag for such cases as webserver passes # to clientside (javascript) to process the hastag content (hence you can pass the link to users of the page)

### http://www.example.com#Tab2Title

you can process the tabs just as you were on the client side using javascript

```
window.history.pushState
```

using this methodolgy is easier and is just what is meant for